# What's the root password for Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: 22.04, password

We installed Ubuntu desktop GUI on our Ubuntu 22.04. We are able to ssh fine into root user of this VM. The problem comes when we try to login using Microsoft Remote Desktop. This screen asks us for a password we did not set.

So far, the only workaround we found was ssh-ing and rebooting the VM to bypass this login screen.

How do I login to this VM graphically? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: When you set up Ubuntu, it asks you to select a password. Then you can `sudo` to root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Root doesnt have a password per default. It's not recommended to use root as a user at all, and I would strongly suggest you use sudo to elevate the commands you need. If you do need to use root, this is possible.

[Link to guide from linuxconfig](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-allow-gui-root-login-on-ubuntu-22-04-jammy-jellyfish-linux)

You need to set a password for root, and then allow root login.

Comment: Thank you. The article was just what we needed.